# for-loop question for spatial buffer in R

Tags: r, loops, gis, workflow, data-manipulation

I am doing a sensitivity analysis for a spatial buffer.

```
buffer_house <- gBuffer(house_prj, width = 1, byid = TRUE)
```

How would I do a for-loop to increase the buffer size for each iteration.

For example a `width = 5` in one iteration up to `width = 100`by running a loop for 5m intervals.

Can anyone help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do this:

```
for(width in seq(5, 100, 5)){
  buffer_house <- gBuffer(house_prj, width = width, byid = TRUE)
}
```

You would still have to save all of those outcomes though. The code I showed you will overwrite `buffer_house` each time.

Comment: Thanks! how would I save each iteration? as a separate dataframe